# Spring OAuth 1.0 passing credentials in request body on POST

Tags: spring-security, oauth

I'm wrestling with OAuth 1.0 and integrating with a 3rd party app.

For a particular POST (an APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED post), they require the OAuth credentials to be passed as part of the form.

Is there a way to tell the Spring OAuth library to NOT pass the oauth credentials in the header (or the URL), and rather, in the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a library that I was able to use that did what I needed.

I was trying to integrate with an LMS system using LTI standards. SO this package did this trick: https://github.com/IMSGlobal/basiclti-util-java